# React Native Android Tv control focus-navigation in a nested FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

For React Native Android Tv Target Can't able to achieve below focus navigation for all touchables.

Steps to Reproduce for Demo::

Take a Flat List where its data should contain A, B & C with respective data in it. (Simpley like OTT home List with respective to title and carousel content)
title would be the header and data would be the other nested Flat List which is Horizontal.
For Example:

```
const dummyArray = [{
id: 1, title: "A", data: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
id: 2, title: "B", data: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
id: 3, title: "C", data: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}];
```

When I Start pressing d'pad down for suppose I'm at section A(at Index-2) from there when I press d'pad down again it is going to section B( to Index-2). Would be this Actual behavior it behaves, but I'm expecting below behavior.
Expected behavior:: it should go to starting index of each Row in the FlatList.

If I'm thinking wrong, could any one put me right path

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Memory: 100.96 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.0, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3
      System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Android TV Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
    Xcode: 12.0.1/12A7300 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_251 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: Not Found
    react-native-macos: Not Found
    react-native-tvos:  0.63.3-0
```